# Problem using Nvidia Driver in Ubuntu 16

Tags: nvidia, display

I'm running Ubuntu 16. I installed latest Nvidia drivers and rebooted. Fail. I only see a flashing cursor. What do I do next?

Nvidia install scripts claim to save a copy of the xorg.conf file. When I look at that file, it's empty:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 May 29 14:15 xorg.conf.nvidia-xconfig-original
```

Can I boot without the X server and somehow uninstall the latest Nvidia driver?

Any other options?

Comment: What are the "atest Nvidia drivers"? How many are they? How did you install them? Lots of questions, not answers. Try to clarify.

Comment: Yes indeed you can boot without X . From the grub menu , press "E" to open the config editor , and put a "3" at the end of the line beginning with the "linux" command , then press Ctrl+X to boot. After booting up , enter your username and password and from the shell either enter "sudo apt remove nvidia-driver-"driver_version" if you've installed it via apt or "your_nvidia_installer.run --uninstall" if you've installed it via the official .run package from Nvidia.Reboot to see if it get solved.

Comment: Another solution is to run "prime-select intel" if you have intel GPU to temporarily disable the Nvidia driver.

Comment: Thank you Parsa.  Your answer contained all of the information I needed to correct the problem.  I give thee one karma dollar.

Comment: You're welcome. And if you want to notify someone via comments , please add the tag @username in your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes indeed you can boot without X.

From the GRUB menu , press <kbd>E</kbd> to open the config editor, and put a `3` at the end of the line beginning with the `linux` command. It should look something like this:

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-46 root=SOME_UUID ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff 3
```

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to boot. After booting up, enter your username and password and from the shell and either enter

```bsh
sudo apt remove nvidia-driver-"your_driver_version"
```

if you've installed it via apt or

```bsh
your_nvidia_installer.run --uninstall"
```

if you've installed it via the official `.run` package from Nvidia. Reboot to see if it got solved.